# What is "algebraic theory" in the wide sense?

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, terminology

The reason why I am asking this question is that the currently referenced as "categorical set theory" (the set theory introduced in the book "*A.Joyal and I.Moerdijk, Algebraic Set Theory. Cambridge University Press, Cambridge 1995.*") does not seem to be an algebraic theory as this notion is defined here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_theory: algebraic theory is a theory that uses axioms stated entirely in terms of equations between terms with free variables.
Also, notice this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_theory,
An elementary theory is a theory that involves axioms using only finitary first-order logic. Saying that a theory is elementary is a weaker condition than saying it is algebraic.

The algebraization method presented in the mentioned book uses infinitary logic. A ZF-algebra used for algebraization of ZF is an algebraic structure which does not look possible to be described in terms of universal algebra. So, per definition of this algebraic structure, for any set $S$ in the ZF's universe (which is a proper class) there must exist an operation in the ZF-algebra which produces the union of any family of sets indexed by the set $S$. Thus, both some operations of a ZF-algebra can be infinitary and the signature of ZF-algebra is a proper class.

My understanding is that the authors of the book used the term "algebraic set theory" treating "algebraic theory" in wide sense. Can the meaning of this term so generalized be described in precise terms?

Comment: Yes, the language is not precise here. If we cancel the word "number" from "Algebraic Number Theory" we don't obtain an algebraic theory. So if you cancel "set" from Moedijk's "Algebraic Set Theory"...

Comment: See Aowdey's [Why "algebraic set theory"?](https://www.phil.cmu.edu/projects/ast/whyast.html), which gives two justifications for this name.

Comment: The categorical set theory with its ZF-algebras is the result of algebraization of ZF set theory, not of other set theories or of set theory as a discipline. Therefore, one would expect the result of algebraization to be an algebraic theory. Anyway, the main theme in my question is how could be expressed in precise terms the widest meaning of the term "algebraic theory" . Knowing this one would also know for example this: 
**Is the theory of a quasi-variety of universal algebras an algebraic theory?**

Comment: @varkor The Awodey's justifications are formulated in terms of category theory  ("monads" and "functors") and these are difficult to be reformulated to the terms of universal algebra.

Comment: @IoachimDrugus: "algebraic" is often used interchangeably with "monadic" in category theory because of the correspondence between algebraic theories and monads.

Comment: Is there a conception and a term in category theory which corresponds to quasi-variety in universal algebra? Also, is there a conception and term in category theory which corresponds to "theory of a quasi-variety of algebras"? I am asking these two questions because a conception wider than ``algebraic theory" is obviously "theory of a quasi-variety of algebras", which lacks a name in universal algebra.

Comment: I don't see how the axioms of AST use infinitary logic. Forget about ZF-algebras, AST itself is the theory of a particular kind of pretopos, the structure of which can be described in the first-order language of categories, which is itself essentially algebraic (https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/essentially+algebraic+theory)

Comment: So the theory is not algebraic in the sense of the WP article, but at best _essentially algebraic_ (I don't know the exact signature, though, one might need geometric logic). For a category theorist, this is still very algebraic in flavour.

Comment: @theHigherGeometer So, the meaning of *essentially algebraic theory* (EAT) is wider that the meaning of *algebraic theory*. My knowledge of category theory is not sufficient to properly understand the definition of EAT . Does it say that there can be infinitely many operations in the signature of an EAT, but each operation is finitary?

Comment: The finitely many/infinitely many distinction is nearly orthogonal, what's important is that the domain of any operation is given by a subset of a finite product, carved out by at most finitely many equations using other operations.

Comment: @theHigherGeometer "The domain of any operation is given by a subset of a finite product" means that the operations are "partial" (not "total"). But then, the condition that the operation is defined for a n-tuple of values of an n-ary operation must be an antecedent in each axiom of the theory, and thus, all axioms must be quasi-identities. This bring to my hypothesis that the theories of quasi-varieties, which could be described as **quasi-algebraic theories** are "algebraic" in a pretty wide sense. Does this sound correct?

Comment: I don't know anything about universal algebra when written in that language. Yes, the operations are partial, a good example is the theory of (small) categories. Composition is a partial function defined on the square of the set of morphisms. I don't know what you mean by quasi-identities and so on, I'm afraid. I'm only adding clarifying remarks, I can't answer your question, sorry.